# How to show Checkbox against each Row based on Column value - JQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, datatables

I am using below code for showing checkbox in Jquery Datatable.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
  'columnDefs': [
     {
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': {
           'selectRow': true
        }
     }
  ],
  'select': {
     'style': 'multi',
     'selector': 'td:first-child'
  },     
  'order': [[1, 'asc']]
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/09yLegu3/

I have a new requirement where i want show checkbox only based on a column value.I have column with name Office.Checkbox should be displayed only if Office value is "Tokyo".How can i achieve this jquery data table. Can anyone help with a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the [columns rendering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) you can block the checkbox rendering.

Morever, on [columns created Cell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) you can [disable the checkbox](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/reference/api/#cell().checkboxes.disable()).

Your **columnDefs** becomes (in order to remove checkboxes for **London**):

```
'columnDefs': [
    {
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
        },
        'render': function(data, type, row, meta){
            data = '<input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes">'
            if(row[3] === 'London'){
                data = '';
            }
            return data;
        },
        'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
            if(rowData[3] === 'London'){
                this.api().cell(td).checkboxes.disable();
            }
        }
    }
],
```

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
    'columnDefs': [
        {
            'targets': 0,
            'checkboxes': {
                'selectRow': true,
                'selectAllCallback': function(nodes, selected, indeterminate) {
                    if (indeterminate == false) {
                        $(nodes).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', selected );
                    }
                },
                'selectCallback': function(nodes, selected) {
                    if (selected == false) {
                        $(nodes).closest('table').find('thead tr').removeClass('selected');
                    }
                }
            },
            'render': function(data, type, row, meta){
                data = '<input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes">'
                if(row[3] === 'London'){
                    data = '';
                }
                return data;
            },
            'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                if(rowData[3] === 'London'){
                    this.api().cell(td).checkboxes.disable();
                } else {
                    td.classList.add('dt-checkboxes-cell-visible');
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    'select': {
        'style': 'multi',
        'selector': 'td:first-child'
    },
    'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

```css
table.dataTable thead th.dt-checkboxes-select-all input[type="checkbox"],
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-checkboxes-cell-visible input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
table.dataTable td.dt-checkboxes-cell-visible,
table.dataTable th.dt-checkboxes-select-all {
    position: relative;
}
table.dataTable td.dt-checkboxes-cell-visible:before,
table.dataTable td.dt-checkboxes-cell-visible:after,
table.dataTable th.dt-checkboxes-select-all:before,
table.dataTable th.dt-checkboxes-select-all:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.2em;
    left: 50%;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table.dataTable td.dt-checkboxes-cell-visible:before,
table.dataTable th.dt-checkboxes-select-all:before {
    content: ' ';
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
table.dataTable tr.selected td.dt-checkboxes-cell-visible:after,
table.dataTable tr.selected th.dt-checkboxes-select-all:after {
    content: '\2714';
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #B0BED9, -1px -1px #B0BED9, 1px -1px #B0BED9, -1px 1px #B0BED9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.10/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.10/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>

<h3><a href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/">jQuery DataTables Checkboxes</a>: <a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/integration/select/">Select extension</a></h3>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Extn</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary Value</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<hr><a target="_blank" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/integration/select/">See full article on Gyrocode.com</a>
```

Comment: @gaetanoM..really sorry..its my mistake...now it is working..i wil mark it as answer after testing..Thank you so much friend..People like you making this place a heaven

Comment: ..one more doubt..is any way i can implement checkbox style similar that we seeing in the below fiddle using ur implementation ..https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/yxLrLr8o/..

Comment: @vmb  Snippet updated. Now the checkbox style has the desired aspect.

Comment: @gaetanoM..Thank you so much for you effort.I have implemented your new code and need a help to fix some issue.(1).I want to programatically disabling all checkbox.I am using  $('#example tbody tr').removeClass('selected'); and it works for all elements except "SelectAll" checkbox.How can i programatically uncheck all the checkbox inside table 'example" including "SelectAll" checkbox.I tried $('#example').find('thead tr').removeClass('selected'); and it is not working.

Comment: @gaetanoM..Another important issue i noted is if any of the tbody checkbox is unchecked,then "Select All" checkbox also should be unchecked(this feature was there in previous code snippet).But it is not handled in the new implentation.Also createdCell throwing an error when we adding a new row to the existing table.(as workaround now i put try catch where it throwing error)

Comment: @ gaetanoM ...i think above mentioned issue is specific to my implementation. I have done a workaround for fixing those issue...Thank you so much for you support for achieving this functionality

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by calling the [`drawCallback()`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) function when initializing `DataTable` and, inside it, check in each row if the column for office contains "Tokyo"; if so, remove the checkbox from the 1st column:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
    'columnDefs': [{
      'targets': 0,
      'checkboxes': {
        'selectRow': true
      }
    }],
    'select': {
      'style': 'multi',
      'selector': 'td:first-child'
    },
    'order': [
      [1, 'asc']
    ],
    "drawCallback": function() {
      $("#example tr").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find("td:eq(3)").text() != "Tokyo") {
          $($(this)).find("td:eq(0)").find("input[type='checkbox']").remove();
        }

      });
    }
  });
});
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4reu5nx/).

Answer (score 1):

i have executed this code and it is working fine as you expected, in your code you just had to put the condition on the basis of the particular row of "office" parameter like mentioned below that will help you to achieve at the time of binding the data.

```
Here is the fiddle link : [https://jsfiddle.net/nzL39dye/3/][1]

Or

 $(document).ready(function() {
       var table = $('#example').DataTable({
          ajax: 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
          columnDefs : [
            { 
             targets : [0],
             render : function (data, type, row) {

              if (row[3] == "Tokyo") 
              {
                return '<input type="checkbox"  selectRow="true" class="dt-checkboxes">'
              }
                else {
                return '';

                }
              }
            }
       ],
          select: {
             style: 'multi',
             selector: 'td:first-child'
          },     
          order: [[1, 'asc']]
       });
    });

   }
```

This solution is simple and easy to understand.